# Simple way to detect collision between two bitmaps on android surface view

Tags: android, collision-detection

I'm looking for a standard way to detect collision between two bitmaps inside a surface view. I tried the intersect method with two rectangles, but it doesn't log.

```
practiseA = new Rect(500, 500, 500, 500);
practiseB = new Rect(500, 500, 500, 500);

public void isIntersecting() {
    Log.d("yeah", "hello");
    if (practiseA.intersect(practiseB)) {
        Log.d("collision", "yes");
    }
}
```

So can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or give me a different method?

I saw this complicated algorithm but didn't understand what to feed it:

```
sqrt( ( ax - bx ) ^ 2 + ( ay - by) ^ 2) <= aR + bR
```

What's `aR` and `bR`?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the classes in Rect, specifically .intersects(Rect a, Rect b) is boolean and saves having to do all the math yourself.

Answer (score 1):

> I saw this complicated algorithm but didn't understand what to feed it:
>
> ```
> sqrt( ( ax - bx ) ^ 2 + ( ay - by) ^ 2) <= aR + bR
> ```
>
> What's aR and bR?

`sqrt( ( ax - bx ) ^ 2 + ( ay - by) ^ 2)` computes the distance between `a` and `b`, assuming they're objects with a 2d position.

`aR` and `bR` are probably the radii of `a` and `b`, so we can assume that `aR + bR` are the sum of these radii.

Thus we can assume that `sqrt( ( ax - bx ) ^ 2 + ( ay - by) ^ 2) <= aR + bR` checks if the two bodies `a` and `b` (which are probably circles because of the concept of radius) overlap (because the distance separating them is shorter than the sum their radii).

A more efficient option would probably be

```
( ( ax - bx ) ^ 2 + ( ay - by) ^ 2) <= ( ( aR + bR ) ^ 2 )
```

Because `sqrt` is generally more costly than squaring a value.